# Azure.Identity.VisualStudioCredential with IIS appPoolIdentity

Tags: c#, iis, azure-keyvault, always-encrypted

I'm in my way to use Always Encrypted on an existing .Net Framework 4.8 WebApi codebase. The solutions runs locally (for development) on IIS on ApplicationPoolIdentity (Windows 10).

I've set up a sql query which accesses a SQL Server database with an encrypted column.

I'm using `VisualStudioCredential` locally to access the key vault.

Running the same code from a simple console app works, but when running on IIS `VisualStudioCredential` cannot access the token provider file under `C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local.IdentityService\AzureServiceAuth\tokenprovider.json`.

Indeed this file does not exists, it does exists in `C:\Users\<my-username>\AppData\Local.IdentityService\AzureServiceAuth`.

It tried running the pool under my own identity, but then it search the file `C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local.IdentityService\AzureServiceAuth\tokenprovider.json` which does not exists.

Any suggestion on how to get it to work would be appreciated.

[Edit]
I have tried pretty  much all the TokenCredential implementation available under `Azure.Identity` with no success. I think `VisualStudioCredential` is the way to go, but I'm open to other suggestions. Even an interactive prompt would be OK for me since it is for development purpose, but `InteractiveBrowserCredential` fails on the worker process.

Comment: can you not specify the location of the tokenprovider in say the app.config or web.config?

Comment: The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity.visualstudiocredential?view=azure-dotnet) does not mention anything in that sense

Comment: but the said documentation is pretty minimal

Comment: Microsoft expects developers to have extensive knowledge on Windows user accounts, so the documentation page you referred to won't have more details. In your case, setting `LoadUserProfile` to `true` might help, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities#user-profile

Comment: @LexLi this property is already true on my app pool :/

Comment: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/4590#issuecomment-414838241

Comment: thanks @LexLi I will try this next monday. In the meantime, have a great weekend ;)

Comment: What version of `Microsoft.Azure.Serivecs.AppAuthentication` are you using? It seems to be a bug in versions prior to 1.6 and has been fixed in 1.6.  https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/12035

Comment: @BruceZhang I don't use this package. I installed `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` and `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.AlwaysEncrypted.AzureKeyVaultProvider` which comes with a lot of dependencies, but not this one.

Answer (score 0):

[The link](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/4590#issuecomment-414838241) posted by @LexLi in the comments explains the problem.

`Azure.Identity.VisualStudioCredential` cannot be used with ApplicationPoolIdentity on IIS. The pool must run under the developer's name.

I ended up configuring an application in azure AD for dev environments and using clientId/clientSecret.

Comment: What would "running under the developers name" mean in terms of the IIS settings? Would it be the `Built-in account `> `LocalSystem option`? Tried the suggestions at the link without success.

Comment: > What would "running under the developers name" mean in terms of the IIS settings?

- It means the application pool is running under a specific user, this user being the developper ad account. I'm not sure of the precise term because my installation of windows is in french.

Comment: Appreciate the response. I found the answer for how to do it elsewhere and documented it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75096380/5012644).